# MongoDB C# Serialize embedded object as flatten object

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm planning to save all entities with same 'container' object that provides common metadata of the actual object. for example:

```cs
public class Entity<T> where T : class
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
  //... and others...
  public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
  // ...and so on...
}
```

An entity will be saved like this:

```
{
  "_id": UUID("xxxxx...xxxx"),
  "createdTime": "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000z",
  "value": {
    "name": "foo",
    "age": 42,
  }
}
```

I want to serialize(/deserialize) like this:

```
{
  "_id": UUID("xxxxx...xxxx"),
  "_createdTime": "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000z",
  "name": "foo",
  "age": 42,
}
```

(`createdTime` is also changed to `_createdTime`)

I'm not sure if I can this with `IBsonSerializer` or `IBsonDocumentSerializer`.

Comment: I don't think what you are trying to do has anything to do with MongoDB. You are just trying to flatten a json object, that's it. I know [Automapper](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html) provide these sort of functionality. checkout their document for more info.

Comment: Yes, it would be. But I'm looking for MongoDB C# API if possible, so that I don't need to add additional dependencies. MongoDB C# API looks like to provide those functionality but I just failed to figure out it.

Comment: I guess the only way is to use $reduce, or $unwind commands on MongoDB query before returning the results. But I doubt if you can do such thing natively from your Business Layer in C#.

Comment: @Benjamin I used to do something similar with JSON(JSON.NET). BSON in MongoDB, it's quite different.

As you said, I prefer to stick with my code. Well, a `Dictionary<string, object>` mapping by using AutoMapper will be the simplest way for now.

But I'll not close this issue because some brilliant idea could be posted.
Thanks for your advice.